# Excel: Bring Chart to Front Based on Cell Value

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I've created a dashboard of sorts for displaying financial data for a customer. The issue is this: one of the charts is a total by year chart like this:

[image]

However, that's not always appropriate for all slicers. For example, if I had a personnel count slicer, a cumulative total graph would be useless, but an average personnel count graph would be valuable. I am trying to figure out how to have the appropriate chart display depending on a cell value (which is dictated by the slicers). For example, if the personnel count slicer is selected, then bring the average chart to the front. Else, bring the total chart to the front.

I've tried placing the below in ThisWorkbook with no success:

```
Private Sub ChartDisplay()

If Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B1") = "Headcount" Then
 ActiveSheet.Shapes("chrtYearTotal").ZOrder msoBringToFront
 Else: ActiveSheet.Shapes("chrtYearAvg").ZOrder msoBringToFront
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: maybe you mean `If Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B1") = "Headcount" Then` ? are you comparing it to the cell content ? or a variable named `Headcount` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado sorry about that - that was a typo when I changed the value. The quotes are there. Good point, though!

Comment: Please edit your post with your correct code,

Comment: Anyway, your code works nicely on my charts, how is "B1" getting the value from your slicers?

Comment: Strange....your charts are changing automatically when you change slicers? "B1" is a filter cell on a pivot table that is connected to my slicer.